# More work like Judea Pearl's Heuristics?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, history, heuristics

I am researching formal and informal search heuristics. One of the best books on the subject I've found is Judea Pearl's Heuristics. Embarrassingly, I find myself unable to find a good search strategy that returns more material in this vein.
Things I am looking for:

- Summary papers about advances in search
- Books/papers that cover some of the history of the development of methods
- Some idea about who is currently producing research in this space and their specialization
- Additional keywords, search methods, and items that should appear on this list to broaden the search

I'm looking for non-technical material. Most works have a bunch of specific implementation detail and small, short bits about where the research came from and what it lead to (which leads to me chasing citation trails). This is totally fine, but hoping to find works that include more of the non-technical info all in one place.
Some works I've canvassed so far:

- Search and Optimization by Metaheuristics. Techniques and Algorithms Inspired by Nature
- Metaheuristics: from design to implementation
- Artificial Intelligence, Evolutionary Computing and Metaheuristics: In the Footsteps of Alan Turing
- Essays and Surveys in Metaheuristics
- Essentials of Metaheuristics
- Handbook of approximation algorithms and metaheuristics
- Heuristics, Metaheuristics and Approximate Methods in Planning and Scheduling
- Recent Advances on Meta-Heuristics and Their Application to Real Scenarios
- Advances in Knowledge Representation
- Applications of Conceptual Spaces: The Case for Geometric Knowledge Representation
- Concepts, Ontologies, and Knowledge Representation
- Handbook of Knowledge Representation

I realize this is more an academically oriented question and am also open to suggestions of where else to post such a question.

Comment: This is likely more on-topic on [Programmers](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to another site in the SE network.

Comment: Ask in Computer Science Stack Exchange